# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta a una base de datos Oracle pasando un Sequence como parámetro en Spring Boot?

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, jpa, mybatis

Estoy trabajando con Spring Boot y Java 8. Intento hacer una consulta para obtener un Id, el problema es que el parámetro que le paso es una secuencia, o sea ni un String ni un entero:

**OPCIÓN 1. Pruebo con Mybatis** pasando el parámetro como si fuese un String:

```
@Select("SELECT #{variable} FROM DUAL") 
Integer getDato(@Param("variable") String variable);
```

**OPCIÓN 2. Pruebo Con jpa hibernate**:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT :variable FROM DUAL ")     
public Integer getDato(@Param("variable") String variable);
```

En ambos casos, *variable* es una variable tal que así: `TEXTO_NUMERO.nextval`, es decir yo le paso la secuencia y necesito que me devuelva el Id que necesito. El que se devuelve en Oracle con esta consulta:

```
SELECT TEXTO_NUMERO.nextval FROM DUAL
```

Por más que lo intento no me funciona. Ahora el problema parece ser que **interpreta el dato *variable* como un String**, ¿sabéis cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute esto?:

```
SELECT VARIABLE_NUMERO.nextval FROM DUAL
```

En lugar de que se ejecute esto:

```
SELECT 'TEXTO_NUMERO.nextval' FROM DUAL
```

P.D.: He intentado pasar en vez de TEXTO y NUMERO solo el dato NUMERO como un entero y construir algo como:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT TEXTO_:variable.nextval FROM DUAL ")       
public Integer getDato(@Param("variable") Integer variable);
```

o algo como

```
@Select("SELECT TEXTO_#{variable}.nextval FROM DUAL")
Integer getDato(@Param("variable") Integer variable);
```

Pero así da otro error.

Necesito pasar un parámetro que no es un String realmente y no sé cómo hacerlo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer algo así?

Comment: Vas a tener que usar EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que habría que crear un procedimiento, llamarlo pasando el dato y que devuelva el ID? Gracias.